# How to SELECT an array of all associated records IDs in PotgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following relation:

```
Place(1) |----< (N)SavedPlace(N) >----| (1)Visitor
```

So:

- One `Place` can be saved by many `Visitors`
- One `SavedPlace` saves exactly one `Place`
- One `SavedPlace` is saved exactly by one `Visitor`
- One `Visitor` can save many `Places`

I want to:

- count how many times one `Place` was saved in general - I imagine this as joining `Places` with `SavedPlaces`, grouping them by `Place` ID and counting how many `SavedPlaces` ID are per each group
- see if a `Visitor` saved a `Place` - I imagine this as having a list of `Visitors` IDs for every place.

The first one I did with:

```
from place in query,
  left_join: saved_places in assoc(place, :saved_places),
  group_by:  place.id,
  select:    %{place | saved_count:  count(saved_places.id)}
```

For the second one, I have no idea.

How should SQL look like to query for both of these values?

---

EDIT:

I realized that I didn't describe the second use case correctly. I'd like to query for all `Places` and for each of them tell if they were saved by a particular `Visitor` (knowing his ID of course).

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: You want to write the query to get 1) Each of the place and how many times it has saved 2) List of visitors who has visited a given place ?

Comment: You marked your question with `sql`, but the code you provided at the end is not plain `sql`. Are you using some framework?

Comment: @trincot it doesn't matter because I cannot translate SQL code to that framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look for two queries:

> count how many times one Place was saved in general - I imagine this as joining Places with SavedPlaces, grouping them by Place ID and counting how many SavedPlaces ID are per each group

```
select     places.place_id, places.place_name, Count(*)
from       places
inner join savedplaces on savedplaces.place_id = places.place_id
group by   places.place_id, places.place_name
```

If it is possible for a visitor to save a place twice (does that make sense in your application?), *and* you want to count such duplicates only once, then replace `Count(*)` with `Count(distinct savedplaces.visitor_id)`.

For the other request:

> see if a Visitor saved a Place - I imagine this as having a list of Visitors IDs for every place.

```
select     places.place_id, places.place_name, visitors.visitor_id, visitors.visitor_name
from       places
inner join savedplaces on savedplaces.place_id = places.place_id
inner join visitors on visitors.visitor_id = savedplaces.visitor_id
```

To know the visitors that saved a particular place, add a `where` clause:

```
where      places.place_id = ?
```

... where `?` represents whatever place_id you want to get the visitors for.

Similarly, to know the places a particular visitor saved, use a `where` clause:

```
where      places.visitor_id = ?
```

... where `?` represents whatever visitor_id you want to get the saved places for.

In case you want to list all places, and an indication of whether a particular visitor has saved it (yes/no), then you could use an outer (`left`) join:

```
select     places.place_id, places.place_name, 
           case when savedplaces.visitor_id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end
from       places
left join  savedplaces on savedplaces.place_id = places.place_id
       on  savedplaces.visitor_id = ?
```

Similarly, in case you want to list all visitors, and an indication of whether they saved a particular place (yes/no), then you could use an outer (`left`) join as well:

```
select     visitors.visitor_id, visitors.visitor_name, 
           case when savedplaces.place_id is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end
from       visitors
left join  savedplaces on savedplaces.visitor_id = visitors.visitor_id
       on  savedplaces.place_id = ?
```

Comment: What if for all places I want to know if they were saved by a particular visitor?

Comment: Added two more queries to my answer, one of which answers that query.

Answer (score 1):

You may write the query as follows

1)

```
SELECT p1.name, x.placeCount
FROM Place p1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT p2.id, COUNT(s.placeId) as placeCount
FROM Place p2 
INNER JOIN SavedPlace s
ON p2.id = s.placeId
GROUP BY p2.id ) x
ON p1.id = x.id
```

2)

```
SELECT v.name
FROM SavedPlace s
INNER JOIN Visitor v
ON s.vistorId = v.id
WHERE s.placeId = <your_place_id>
```